# How do I return this as a list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have this data:

```
inventory = { HAMMER: (10,100),
              SCREW: (1, 1000),
              NAIL: (1, 1000),
              SCREWDRIVER: (8, 100),
              DRILL: (50, 20),
              WORKBENCH: (150, 5),
              HANDSAW: (15, 50),
              CHAINSAW: (80, 30)
            }
```

Which I have written the following function:

```
def get_items(cheapness):
    """ Return a list of (item, (price, count)) tuples that are the given
    cheapness. Note that the second element of the tuple is another tuple. """

    if cheapness == 'CHEAP':
        return [(key, value) for (key,value) in inventory.items() if value in ((cost,quantity) for (cost, quantity) in inventory.values() if cost < 20)]
    elif cheapness == 'MODERATE':
        return [(key, value) for (key,value) in inventory.items() if value in ((cost,quantity) for (cost, quantity) in inventory.values() if 20 < cost < 100)]
    elif cheapness == 'EXPENSIVE':
        return [(key, value) for (key,value) in inventory.items() if value in ((cost,quantity) for (cost, quantity) in inventory.values() if cost > 100)]
```

My problem is when I do a `print type(get_items(CHEAP))`, I get `<type 'NoneType'>`. How do I return the results as a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say what you mean:

```
def get_items(cheapness):
    """ Return a list of (item, (price, count)) tuples that are the given
    cheapness. Note that the second element of the tuple is another tuple. """

    if cheapness == 'CHEAP':
        return [(item, (price,count)) for (item, (price,count)) in inventory.items() if price < 20]
    elif cheapness == 'MODERATE':
        return [(item, (price,count)) for (item, (price,count)) in inventory.items() if price > 20 and price < 100]
    elif cheapness == 'EXPENSIVE':
        return [(item, (price,count)) for (item, (price,count)) in inventory.items() if price > 100]
```

Comment: But it was the solution the OP understood at this point in time due to his noobness. Stay classy.

Answer (score 5):

This code is more functional and may be easier to maintain:

```
def get_items(cheapness):
    def a(value):
        if cheapness == 'CHEAP':
            return value < 20
        if cheapness == 'MODERATE':
            return value >= 20 and value < 100
        if cheapness == 'EXPENSIVE':
            return value >= 100
        return False
    return filter(lambda x: a(x[1][0]), inventory.items())
```

Comment: I haven't really reached the use of lambda's yet I'm afraid. I quite like Russell Borogove's answer though. How is yours more Pythonic may I ask?

Comment: I always ask myself how I can do something better when I see the same line of code repeated more than once. In your case, you are writing out the same list comprehension three times. The only difference is the conditional statement. Mine pulls the conditional statement out into a function and takes advantage of the functional tools built into Python (ie: `filter` and `lambda`).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say more Pythonic, myself; it is more in the Functional Programming style. It scales a little better than my solution when the filtering condition gets more complex.

Comment: Fair enough. This code would also be easier to maintain in the long run. Say you have to add three more `cheapness` levels. In your code, that means copy/paste the list comprehension and modify the conditional. Now what happens when the inventory dictionary changes (say you add rating value to the tuple)? You now have six lines you have to change. With my code, you have one. PS: Edited my answer to point out that it's more functional than Pythonic.

Comment: @RJ Regenold That's a good point. Thanks. But I'm gonna accept Russell's because it's the solution I understand at this point in time due to my noobness.

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted to offer up an alternative. Good luck in your Python'ing!

Answer (score 1):

what about print type(get_items('CHEAP'))? (note the quotes)

Comment: Actually, I think this is your immediate problem. All your cases should at worst be returning [], not None; you're falling off the end of get_items() without a return. But my answer is still clearer and more efficient (he said, modestly).